# How to display variables in python without using print()

Tags: python-3.x, user-interface, tkinter

I'm a reallyyyy new user to python, and mostly used Matlab before so still trying to understand the workings of python.

I've managed to write a program that detects ARUCO markers using a camera and calculates their pose vectors: a 3D translation list (# of markers, 1,3) and another for rotation (# of markers, 1,3).

I currently use print() to display the two vectors in "time" ( refresh with the camera's fps)...and trying to figure out if a separate window could be used to display them and refresh with each new frame.

I have done some looking into tkinter but it wasn't really working for me. I am not sure if there is a smarter or easier way to do this.

** only using arbitrary values right now to set up the code and then my plan was to create a function where I could feed in the marker ids, translationvectors, rotation  vectors**

````
#Purpose: Create a Ouput GUI for output of Translation and Rotation Vectors

#def disp_PoseVal(ids, combpairs, id_rvec, id_tvec, r_rel, t_rel)
#marker id 
a=[3.5, 2.5, 8]
a = " ".join(str(elem) for elem in a)
#a_str=''.join(a)
print(a)
#tranlation
#need to add an asterix to unpack range!
b = [[*range(3)], [*range(2,5)], [*range(8,11)]] 
print(b)   
#rotation                   
c=b

rootwindow = tk.Tk()
rootwindow.title("ARUCO Marker Pose information")
rootwindow.geometry('{}x{}'.format(800, 500))

#Frame 0: IDs
frame_0 = tk.LabelFrame(rootwindow,text="Detected Marker IDs")
frame_0.pack(side="top")

#Read IDs
rids = tk.Text(frame_0)
rids.insert("end",a)
rids.grid(row=0,columnspan=2)
#rids.pack()


#Frame 1: WRT to camera
frame_1 = tk.LabelFrame(rootwindow, height=100, text="Pose Vectors: Tranlation+ Rotation")
frame_1.pack()

#Translation Vector
Trans=tk.Text(frame_1)
for x in b:
    ttemp = " ".join(str(x))
    print(ttemp)
    print('type',type(ttemp))
    Trans.insert("end", ttemp + '\n')
Trans.grid(row=1,column=0)


#Rotation Vector
Rot=tk.Text(frame_1)
for y in c:
    rtemp = " ".join(str(y))
    print(rtemp)
    print('type', type(rtemp))
    Rot.insert("end", rtemp + '\n')
Rot.grid(row=1, column=1)

rootwindow.mainloop()```
````

Comment: Yes, you can use tkinter to display text data. You'll probably want to make a loop with `rootwindow.after` to updatet the display with every frame. Does that answer your question?

Comment: Awesome, thank you! Just working on getting the layout right. Wondering if you might have some general feedback (e.g tips, better practice, etc) Thank you again.

Comment: You could also use flask to set up a server very fast and use HTML templates (I feel that these are great for customization), like if it works for you otherwise even tkinter is good...

Comment: Thank you for the advice! Quite new to this whole thing, so always happy to get some advice or tips!